# Is "it" uncalled here or not?

Tags: grammar

I know that it is OK to say.

**1) I don't understand what is written here.**

but it seems to me that

**2) I don't understand what IT is written here.** is also OK?
 Is my guess correct? If yes, how would you explain the possibility of using IT in the sentence? What difference does it bring into the sentence?

Comment: Unless you add at least a comma to your sentence, the second sentence is _not_ OK. Why would _you_ think it is OK? Did you read this anywhere? At the moment your question feels a bit like "Is this sentence OK? 'there is a _maybe_ cup of tea on the table.' Why can _maybe_ be used there?"

Comment: Look at these two. 1) What is written here? 2) What is it written here? Do you agree that 2 is correct?

Comment: No, I do not agree :) You _could_ say "What is it, that is written here?", but that is certainly not the same sentence. You could also use punctuation: "What!? Is it written _here_?" or "What _is_ it, written here?" Although that last one would need some context to be understandable, I think...

Comment: A: Where is it written? B: It is written here? A: What is it written here? - I though in this context it was OK. I was wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Example (2) has two pronouns side by side: the **relative pronoun** "what" and the **personal pronoun** "it." That is what makes it ungrammatical.

You may be confused by an association with "it is written here that..." in which "it" is a dummy subject, which is used when there is no subject, because English always requires a subject of some sort. However this "it" is dropped when another subject (pronoun or noun) is used.

Comment: What about this one? "I don't know what it is all about." We can't leave "it" out, can we? Why?

Comment: In your first example, you have a passive voice construction. The answer could be "<X> is written". The alternate answer, "<X> it is written"(*) would be ungrammatical. In your second example, you have an active voice construction, and the answer might be "It is all about <x>". The alternative answer, "Is all about <x>" would again be ungrammatical, because it would contain no subject.